# What is the client DOM Code Injection in lightning component?

Tags: security-scanner

The security scanner alert us about client DOM code injection on this lines:

```
L 110: event.data.charge.Auctifera__Contribution__c = recordId
...
L 134: params['chargeData'] = JSON.stringify(event.data.charge)
...
L 136: payAction.setParams(params)
...
L 137: payAction.setCallback(this, (response)=>{
...
L 91: window.addEventListener('message', (event)=>{
```

The completed code is:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event)=>{
  if(component && component.isValid() && event.data.messageType){

 ....

  if (component.get("v.record").Auctifera__Membership_Program__c != null) {
     event.data.charge.Auctifera__Contribution__c = recordId; 
  } else{
     event.data.charge.Auctifera__Donation__c = recordId;
  }

 .... 

  params['chargeData'] = JSON.stringify(event.data.charge);

  payAction.setParams(params);
  payAction.setCallback(this, (response)=>{
    component.set('v.showSpinner', false);
    const state = response.getState();

    ....

  }

  ....

}
```

I don't find the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This is a duplicate of your previous question, which was initially closed for not being clear/including sufficient details. Duplicating questions is frowned upon, and such questions usually attract a lot of negative attention. Generally speaking, the more details you can provide (code, error messages, research you've done, etc...), the better.